# Mudar a cor do elemento <progress>

Tags: css, html5, css3

Estou querendo alterar a cor da barra de progresso,mas não estou conseguindo,Como posso mudar a cor do elemento `<progress>` pelo css?

Comment: Poste o código que vc já desenvolveu para ficar mais fácil de receber ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode alterar as cores mudando o valor de `background-color` nos pseudo-elementos abaixo:

- `::-moz-progress-bar`
- `::-ms-fill`
- `::-webkit-progress-bar`
- `::-webkit-progress-value`
- `::-webkit-progress-inner-element`

**Exemplo comentando:**

```css
progress {
  /* Altera a cor do background no Firefox e navegadores da Microsoft */
  background: yellow;

  /* É necessário alterar o valor para none */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* Altera a cor de fundo em navegadores com webkit (Chrome, Safari etc) */
::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: orange;
}

/* Altera a cor da barra em navegadores com webkit (Chrome, Safari etc) */
::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: green;
}

/* Altera a cor da barra em navegadores com moz (Firefox) */
::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: blue
}

/* Altera a cor da barra em navegadores da Microsoft (IE e Edge) */
::-ms-fill {
  background-color: purple
}
```

```html
<progress value="10" max="50">
```